# Class instance based on input parameter using Guice binding

Tags: java, design-patterns, guice

I have Java interface classes.

```
public interface ModelClient {
}

public interface DownstreamService1Client extends ModelClient {
   public ContentData getContentData();
}

public interface DownstreamService2Client extends ModelClient {
   public ContentData getContentData();
}

public interface DownstreamService3Client extends ModelClient {
   public ContentData getContentData();
}
```

I have another spec builder method:

```
ModelClientSpec<DownstreamService1Client> spec = ModelClientSpec.builder(DownstreamService1Client.class);
```

Above spec can be used to create a client:

```
DownstreamService1Client client = context.getResourceClient(spec);
```

which can be used to call downstream client to get data:

```
ContentData data = client.getContentData(); // get the data from downstream service.
```

I have created following client spec static map:
"contentType" -> DownstreamClientSpec

```
"music" -> DownstreamClient1Spec
"books" -> DownstreamClient2Spec
...
```

Now I have a handler method:

```
public ContentData handle(String contentType) {

    // need to get a client based on contentType
    client = ???
    return  client.getContentData()
}
```

How do I get the client based on the contentType other than having the switch statement for contentType and specific client creation logic? Is it a clean way to dynamically bind the specific client using Guice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess, [Multibindings](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Multibindings), and specifically `MapBinder` can be used to achieve what you are looking for. Bind your client to a map, inject it and get specific implementation from that map by key.